# I want to make own dom in js

Tags: javascript

```
var dom = (function(){
    var tags = [
        'h1', 'h2', 'h3', 'h4', 'h5', 'h6',
        'div', 'span', 'bold', 'small', 'strong',
        'script', 'style'
    ];
    var myObj = {};
    for(var index in tags) {
        var tag = tags[index];
        var obj = Object.defineProperty(myObj, tag, {
            value: function(attr, html) {
                return document.createElement(tag).innerHTML = html;
            }
        });
    }
    return myObj;
}());
```

i want result like this

```
dom.h1('Hello World') = <h1>Hello World</h1>
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: Thanks, But i want to create it my self, with this kind of implementation.

Comment: I want to create functions dynamically from array and i want name of that function as string inside that function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. When the function is executed the `tag` variable refers to the last string, i.e. the `style` element. So all of the functions generate a `style` element. You should use a self-invoking function or the `Array.prototype.forEach` method.
2. `for ... in` loop is not a good option for iterating through arrays.
3. You should generate the element and update it's content using another statement otherwise the function returns the right-hand side of the assignment:

   ```
   for(var index = 0; index < tags.length; index++) {
       (function(tag) {
           Object.defineProperty(myObj, tag, {
               value: function(attr, html) {
                   var el = document.createElement(tag);
                   el.innerHTML = attr;
                   return el;
               }
           });
       })(tags[index]);
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```
var dom = function () {
    var tags = [
        'h1', 'h2', 'h3', 'h4', 'h5', 'h6',
        'div', 'span', 'bold', 'small', 'strong',
        'script', 'style'
    ];
    var myObj = {};
    tags.forEach(function (t) {
        myObj[t] = function (html) {
            var el = document.createElement(t);
            el.innerHTML = html;
            return el;
        };
    });
    return myObj;
}();
```

if you have a `<div id="out"></div>` somewhere, you can use it with

```
document.getElementById('out').appendChild(dom.h1('header!'));
```